# execCommand == null(it is actually 'null not')

Tags: linux, shell, gradle

I have 2 tasks created in my build.gradle. When I run the task 'remoteCopy' it runs through fine. When I run a tasks which is dependent on 'remoteCopy' I get the below error:

```
Executing task ':importDump' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:importDump FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':importDump'.
> execCommand == null!
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong. The build.gradle is given below:

```
**

 - build.gradle

**

task remoteCopy(type: Exec) {
        workingDir '/workspace/anivash.mutham/R10_CommercePlatform_DEV/buildtools/scripts'
        commandLine './remotecopy.sh'
}


task importDump(dependsOn: remoteCopy,type:Exec) << {
        workingDir '/workspace/anivash.mutham/R10_CommercePlatform_DEV/buildtools/scripts'
        commandLine './importdump.sh'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "importDump" task declaration is not valid, you have to move `workingDir`and `commandLine` out of the `<< { }`/`doLast { }` block, as  they are properties of the [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task.

Try this one:

`task importDump(dependsOn: remoteCopy, type: Exec) {
    workingDir '/workspace/anivash.mutham/R10_CommercePlatform_DEV/buildtools/scripts'
    commandLine './importdump.sh'
}`